# Find and replace tabs or newline characters in Webstorm

Tags: replace, tabs, find, newline, webstorm

I want to delete all my newline and tab characters in a file using Webstorm. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

When using the find/replace tool, make sure Regex is checked and then use the escape character codes to locate the necessary characters:

- \n = newline
- \t = tab

if you leave the replace line blank and select replace all, you can then delete all instances of the specified character.